# Are the lift / drag coefficients considered dimensionless?

Tags: aerodynamics, lift, drag

Since the [lift coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_coefficient), $C_L$, and the [drag coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_coefficient), $C_D$, are obtained by rescaling the full lift and drag by

$$\frac12 \rho A v^2$$

does that mean they're dimensionless numbers?

It's slightly confusing, because after rescaling, $C_L$ and $C_D$ depend on the angle of attack, $\alpha$, which somehow makes me think of $C_L$ and $C_D$ as dimensionful quantities.

Comment: For what it's worth, angles are typically considered dimensionless, too.

Comment: Not considered, but defined! Related: [Why do we use dimensionless expressions in flight mechanics and aerodynamics?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/35268/why-do-we-use-dimensionless-expressions-in-flight-mechanics-and-aerodynamics)

Comment: @Sanchises, yes, but only when they are in radians ;)

Comment: If it helps, the Mach number is also dimensionless. And very obviously not a constant.

Comment: Fun fact: work and torque both have the same dimensions (Newton-meters), but are very different things: Work / energy is based on a dot product (force in the direction of motion), the other on a cross product (force at a distance from a pivot point).  Unfortunately, the way we've constructed our mathematical formalism for doing physics, dimensional analysis doesn't help us sort out $N \times m$ from $N \cdot m$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes they are dimensionless numbers, which does not mean that they are constants. $C_L$ $C_D$ *are* variables. Dimensionless meaning: no physical unit. $$L = C_L \cdot \frac{1}{2} \rho V^2 \cdot A$$ with metric units:

- L [N] = [kg*m/sec$^2$]
- $\rho$ [kg/m$^3$]
- V [m/sec]
- A [m$^2$]

Dimension of $\rho V^2 \cdot A$ = $\frac{kg}{m^3} \cdot \frac{m^2}{s^2} \cdot m^2 = kg \cdot m / sec^2 = N$

Comment: same explanation holds for CD, and very similar for CM, and Ch (hinge moment coefficient), and other aerodynamic coefficients of forces and moments.