# What is Waterline and why is it called so?

Tags: airframe

What is waterline and why is it called so?  Is it same as fuselage reference line?

Answer (score 0):

Water lines (WL) designate location in the height of the aircraft, from ground up.

This is explained more in [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3863/what-is-the-coordinate-system-used-in-an-aircraft?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)